Why does the Cucumber report show only one feature when there should be two?
I have a Maven project with Java using Cucumber to generate the report. It includes Register and Login features. The project executes well, but when reviewing the Cucumber report, only the Login feature appears, and the Register feature does not.
I have checked everything and changed the configurations, but the issue persists. Both features should be shown.




It looks like you may be reusing the same runner for different features. The first execution then overwrites the report from the second. Can't say for sure, you didn't share enough information to reproduce your problem. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
